# Private eth network (geth) - invalid sender - can't send transaction using MetaMask

Tags: go-ethereum, metamask

I want to have private network and deploy there contracts. Solutions like temporary ganache-cli doesn't fit for me, so i found that there is GETH tool.

I succesfully run private ethereum network with geth on windows. I can send transactions using JS geth console, but when i want to deploy contract in Remix or send transaction using MetaMask i got rejected (node error - 'invalid sender').

I hope below are all necessary informations.

---

**EDIT:**

I set up the same network with the same commands on ubuntu and there MetaMask worked fine. Also I connected eth-brownie to (Windows) network and it works correctly as JS geth console.

I guess there is some problem with MetaMask version on Windows (tested on Firefox and Brave) but i can't figure out why.

---

Commands to run eth-network:

```
geth --version
geth.exe version 1.12.0-stable-e501b3b0

mkdir node1 [2]
geth --datadir node1 account new [2]
geth init --datadir node1 genesis.json [2]
bootnode -genkey boot.key
bootnode -nodekey boot.key -verbosity 9 -addr 127.0.0.1:30305 

geth --datadir node1 --port 30306 --bootnodes enode://7febe6c8ef47b5a6b1e047bbd39f87e908ec4e9c734bcfa842ab65380d234557f42fa90152b7a44c5c7c7bb3cf0ff3bfa39ea9dbead24c25ca9bcf33f599913a@127.0.0.1:0?discport=30305
--networkid 123459876  --password node1/password.txt --miner.etherbase 0xa26CC96Da33854C7F0d97373e1BD61198FfaD2FD --mine --unlock
0xa26CC96Da33854C7F0d97373e1BD61198FfaD2FD  --syncmode full
--allow-insecure-unlock --http --http.port 8546 --http.addr 127.0.0.1 --http.api "eth,net,web3" --http.corsdomain '*'  

geth --datadir node2 --port 30307 --bootnodes enode://7febe6c8ef47b5a6b1e047bbd39f87e908ec4e9c734bcfa842ab65380d234557f42fa90152b7a44c5c7c7bb3cf0ff3bfa39ea9dbead24c25ca9bcf33f599913a@127.0.0.1:0?discport=30305
--networkid 123459876 --password node2/password.txt --ipcpath "\ethereum2\geth.ipc" --syncmode full --allow-insecure-unlock --http
--http.port 8545 --http.addr 127.0.0.1 --http.api eth,net,web3 --http.corsdomain '*' --authrpc.port 8552
```

genesis.json file:

```
{
    "config": {
        "chainId": 123459876,
        "homesteadBlock": 0,
        "eip150Block": 0,
        "eip155Block": 0,
        "eip158Block": 0,
        "byzantiumBlock": 0,
        "constantinopleBlock": 0,
        "petersburgBlock": 0,
        "istanbulBlock": 0,
        "muirGlacierBlock": 0,
        "berlinBlock": 0,
        "londonBlock": 0,
        "arrowGlacierBlock": 0,
        "grayGlacierBlock": 0,
        "clique": {
            "period": 5,
            "epoch": 30000
        }
    },
    "difficulty": "1",
    "gasLimit": "800000000",
    "extradata": "0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000a26CC96Da33854C7F0d97373e1BD61198FfaD2FD0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000",
    "alloc": {
        "0x7Ef5369b235D7D4147Cc89F78E80b093Fe7c0B71": {
            "balance": "700000000000000000000000"
        },
        "0xa26CC96Da33854C7F0d97373e1BD61198FfaD2FD": {
            "balance": "500000000000000000000000"
        },
        "0x9867aae97877363152f94544Bd6E552557F72B6D": {
            "balance": "500000000000000000000000"
        }
    }
}
```

I can send transactions to another account created by geth or to MetaMask account using JS geth console:

```
geth attach ipc:\\.\pipe\\ethereum2\geth.ipc
eth.sendTransaction({from: eth.accounts[0],to: eth.accounts[1],value: web3.toWei(1, 'ether')});
eth.sendTransaction({from: eth.accounts[0],to: "0x9867aae97877363152f94544Bd6E552557F72B6D",value: web3.toWei(1, 'ether')});
```

---

MetaMask (version: **10.31.1**) connects automatically with network at **localhost:8545**, and properly shows token's amount.
But when i try to send tokens using MetaMask (there appears information that network is busy...) there is WARN log in the geth node, and on MetaMask nothing happens.

```
WARN [06-21|18:39:31.633] Served eth_sendRawTransaction            conn=127.0.0.1:62527 reqid=8480195562128 duration="219.3µs" err="invalid sender"
```

[image]

Also tried deploy contract on Remix but there is exactly the same error in the node and following one in Remix :

```
creation of SimpleStorage errored: Returned error: {"jsonrpc":"2.0","error":"[ethjs-query] while formatting outputs from RPC '{\"value\":{\"code\":-32603,\"data\":{\"code\":-32000,\"message\":\"invalid sender\"}}}'","id":768243477832561}
```